# Object Array Sorting

Tags: java, sorting

I understand the concept of bubble sorting an array of `Int` but is it possible to apply bubble sorting to an array of objects? Specifically I want to sort by an `int` variable contained within the objects.

Int array only has 1 Int or data member to one element of the array, but Objects has multiple data members and that's the part that really confuses me.

also I've looked into Comparetors such as the CompareTo method of java. From what I learned from doing research on it, Comparetors basically returns the difference in value between two objects. How can I apply this to sorting an array?

Comment: You should research Comparators more closely; they are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Then take a look at [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) - there are a verity available based on what you have at hand ;)

Comment: There's literally dozens of question on SO regarding sorting in Java. Did none of them help?

Answer (score 1):

A [`Comparator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) does not return the difference between two objects. It rather returns the ordering of two respective instances of `T`.

As documentation states:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

The good thing of OOP is the fact that you are able to encapsulate data and behavior and this situation is a clear example. Let's look at this boilerplate code:

```
class HugeClass implements Comparable<HugeClass> {
  // lots of variables

  public int compareTo(HugeClass o) {
    // lots of code to decide if this instance is lesser, equal or greater than o
    // then we return -1, 0 or 1 accordingly
  }
```

Now you can implement your bubble sort easily. Instead that directly doing `if (x < y)`, as you would do with `int`s you will do `if (x.compareTo(y) < 0)`but that's the same story and you don't care about how the ordering is actually computed, you just  rely on the `compareTo` method.

Actually you can write a bubble sort method that is able to perform sorting on every comparable class possible. Eg:

```
public sort(Comparable<?>[] data) {
  .. code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to think about your confusion:

Imagine I have a set of boxes with numbers on them. In the boxes are many objects: big, small, red, green, ... If I ask you to sort the boxes ("objects") by the number on them, you would have no problem. If I asked you instead to look inside the box, and sort them by the size of the green balls, you could probably do it. In either case you are sorting objects...

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe this can help you for your confusion:*

```
public class Test {

 public static A a1 = new A("001", "a", "wa~", 7);
 public static A a2 = new A("001", "c", "wa~", 9);
 public static A a3 = new A("001", "b", "wa~", 3);
 public static A a4 = new A("000", "d", "wa~", 6);

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  A[] voA = new A[] { a1, a2, a3, a4 };

  java.util.Arrays.sort(voA, new Mycomparator());

  A[] newA = new A[voA.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < voA.length; i++)
   System.out.println("[" + i + "]:" + voA[i].A1 + " " + voA[i].A2 + " " + voA[i].A3 + " " + voA[i].A4);
 }
}

class A {
 String A1;
 String A2;
 String A3;
 int A4;

 public A(String oA1, String oA2, String oA3, int oA4) {
  this.A1 = oA1;
  this.A2 = oA2;
  this.A3 = oA3;
  this.A4 = oA4;
 }

}

class Mycomparator implements java.util.Comparator {
 public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
  A a1 = (A) o1;
  A a2 = (A) o2;
  if(a1.A1.compareTo(a2.A1)!=0) {
   return a1.A1.compareTo(a2.A1);
  } else if(a1.A2.compareTo(a2.A2)!=0) {
   return a1.A2.compareTo(a2.A2);
  } else if(a1.A3.compareTo(a2.A3)!=0) {
   return a1.A3.compareTo(a2.A3);
  } else {
   return a1.A4 >a2.A4?1:a1.A4==a2.A4?0:-1;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An object which implements Comparator isn't returning any sort of difference.  It just returns a positive number when it's greater than another object and a negative number when it's less.  That's all the sort function cares about.
You can sort an array of objects (which implement Comparable as follows)

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject>{
  int myInt;
  public int compareTo(MyObject other){
    if(myInt>other.myInt)
      return 1;
    else if(myInt<other.myInt)
      return -1;
    else if(myInt==other.myInt)
      return 0;
    else
      throw new Error("This should never happen");
  }
}
```

then if you have an array

```
MyObject[] arr;
```

You can sort it with

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

The only reason people take the difference is because it's quicker to write

```
myInt - other.myInt
```

than it is to write all those if-else clauses (and it's probably faster on hardware as well)

Comment: `((a-b)>0)?(1):(-1))*(a==b?0:1)`